# Why do I have this difference when subtracting terms to near zero in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, calculator

When I run this into the compiler:

```
print (7/3)
print (4/3)
print (7/3-4/3-1)
print ("")
print (5/3)
print (2/3)
print (5/3-2/3-1)
```

The console outputs:

```
2.3333333333333335
1.3333333333333333
2.220446049250313e-16

1.6666666666666667
0.6666666666666666
0.0
```

Why does the compiler round 7/3 to 5 at the 16th digit?  Other calculators say 7/3 is just 2.333(repeating 3)
Also, why does the compiler round the solution for 5/3 but not 2/3?

Comment: The compiler is not ding much in Python. The *interpreter* does.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Though in this case those expressions are computed at bytecode generation stage rather than at bytecode interpretation stage, thanks to the peephole optimizer, so arguably it _is_ the compiler that's responsible. </pedantic nitpick>

Comment: @MarkDickinson: the Python interpreter does close to no optimizations at all.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38755465/67579).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: As you say, "close to no optimizations", but that's not the same as none. The peephole optimizer does optimize some constant expressions, including the one in the OP. Try `dis.dis(lambda: 7/3-4/3-1)` at a Python 3 prompt to see the generated bytecode.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/36ff451ebae41f09560bff582c95946474d898f8/Python/peephole.c#L232).